# How to Save RL Model after Training

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm new to this forum. I viewed this simple reinforcement learning sarsa code   [This is code link](https://github.com/Madhu009/Deep-math-machine-learning.ai/blob/master/Reinforcement%20learning/Model-Free%20RL%20algorithms/TD/Sarsa%20-%20TD_Control.ipynb)

What i am unable to see is how to store its model, like we used to store weights in CNN in deep learning, so we can just load the model and work it without needing it to train everytime. Is it possible to achieve in this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome @BetaLearner. In the example of the link, the Q-function is stored as a table instead of using a neural network or other kind of function approximator. So, you can simply save the table (actually stored as a `defaultdict`) and load it later without need to train again.